# Is this sentence about AoT correct?

Tags: android, jaotc

ART is based on AOT (ahead-of-time) technology that compiles the code during the installation of the app, increasing the installation time of an app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this statement is correct. **ART** uses **Ahead of Time Approach (AOT)** instead of **JIT**.
**ART** can run native code directly. Whereas the DVM needs to run the compiled **Dex bytecode**.  Hence, **ART** is faster for applications.

**Drawbacks of ART include:**

Increased installation time,

increased reboot time,

increased storage.

Refer link below for more information :

[ART 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime)

[ART 2](https://www.journaldev.com/23464/android-runtime-dvm-vs-art-aot-vs-jit)

[ART 3](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik)